# Use background image instead of border

Tags: css, border

I have a div that needs a 5px border bottom, right and left on hover.

Even if I am using `box-sizing: border-box`, as to not alter the size, I am having trouble because the text inside the div moves when hovering.

I seems the border is affecting the inner padding or something.

Could I recreate this effect with a background-image done with linear gradients in css?

Thank you

Edit:

I have a div

```
#my-div {      
  background-color: green;
}

#my-div:hover {
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  border-left: 5px solid red;        
}
```

Instead of having all this, I would like to do a linear-gradient that looks the same as that, so it would be

```
#my-div:hover {
  // something that would look like if I had done
  // border-right: 5px solid red;
  // border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  // border-left: 5px solid red;
  // background-color: green;    
  background-image: linear-gradient(...);
}
```

and it would look the same as the first one

Comment: share your code but you can consider box-shadow to achieve what you want

Comment: which effect ? the moving text ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif can I do box shadow to show like border bottom left and right?

Comment: @MisterJojo achieve the effect of having a border using linear-gradient

Comment: yes you can, but we need more context. Add your code so we can understand the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif I added the code

Comment: add a full code including the HTML and working example .. we need to see something running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for that ?

```css
#my-div {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(50, 161, 205, 0.5);
  }
#my-div:hover {
  border-image-source:  linear-gradient(to right, red, orange);
  }
```

```html
<div id="my-div"> text not moving on hover </div>
```

Comment: no, I am looking for linear-gradient that will look like a border bottom, left and right. This doesn't work for me

Comment: @user3808307 Please complete your question with the linear-gradient you are looking... and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @user3808307  changed my answer